# Prefill SSN input field but leave last 4 numbers editable

Tags: html

I'm trying to make my SSN input field appear to be a normal text field with XXX-XX-already filled in and only the last 4 numbers able to be added.

```html
<div>
<label>SSN</label>
<input mask="111-11-1111" type="text" placeholder="123-45-6789" maxlength="11" size="11" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the XXX-XX- outside of the textbox and having the user only input the last 4? And then styling the XXX... part to look like it's part of the textbox? Similar to textboxes that have prefixes like `$` or suffixes like `.00` for entering monetary amounts?

Comment: and your question/problem is...?

Comment: You might want to explore this solution: https://codepen.io/teefars/pen/qOjWQY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly hacky, but here's a CSS-only solution with no JavaScript.

The `input` itself only contains the last 4 digits, but you can click anywhere within the "box" to start typing (because it's all a `label` for that `input`).

```css
.ssn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.ssn input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>SSN</label>
  <label class="ssn">XXXX-XX-<input type="text" placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" size="4">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: change `input type="number"` so user can only enter digits